# How to get a 3D plot with logarithmic scale on x axis?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Let's say I want to plot a function $f(x,y)= x^3 y^3 + e^{-x}$ using 3D plot; x runs from 0.00001 to 0.1 and y runs from 1 to 100. Now, I want to have a logarithmic scale along the x-axis. So, how to do that?

I used the following command for 3D plot:

```
Plot3D[x^3 y^3 + Exp[-x], {x, 0.00001, 0.1}, {y, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Use `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None, None}`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [Carl Woll in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194571/how-to-get-a-3d-plot-with-logarithmic-scale-on-x-axis#comment506572_194571), the easiest way it to use the [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option to `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[
  x^3 y^3 + Exp[-x], {x, 0.00001, 0.1}, {y, 1, 100},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None, None},
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Log[x], y, x^3 y^3 + Exp[-x]},{x, 0.00001,0.1}, {y, 1, 100}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```